# jQuery change event is not triggered correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My input value detection works fine in Chrome, but in Internet Explorer the 'change' event is not fired if the user types the enter key. How can I make it work for both browsers and in addition prevent that the event is fired twice in Chrome?

[js fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/vzbmLx9s/1/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="price">
<h2></h2>
```

jQuery

```
var $input = $('.price');

    $input.on('change', function(e) {

        $('h2').text($(this).val());
        //do other calculation
    }).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.which != 13) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).trigger('change');
    })
```

Comment: use `$input.on('keyup',`   event

Comment: @NishitMaheta, sometimes a user wants to enter several digits, it would lose focus on keup

Comment: check this fiddle may be help you https://jsfiddle.net/vzbmLx9s/2/

Answer (score -1):

This has been a problem for a long time, and I don't know why jQuery doesn't automatically handle it. There doesn't seem to be any way to get around two events firing if the browser supports the enter key for onchange, so you just have to work around it:

```
    $input.on('focus', function(e) {
      this.calculationDone = false;
    }).on('change', function(e) {
      if (!this.calculationDone) {
        calculationDone = true;
        $('h2').text($(this).val());
        console.log('done');
        //do other calculation
      }
    }).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.which != 13) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).trigger('change');
    })
```